# using imlib2 and gtk2

Tags: linux, image

Can I use imlib2 with gtk2 or is it better to use it with Qt for image manipulation ?  Or if someone knows if I can use imlib2 with free pascal and/or java that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Mike

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way for screen scraping would be to use [XGetImage](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XGetImage.html) which is part of Xlib and thus you do not need **ANY** additional library or toolkit. Check also [this](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/xgetimage.html)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

I wouldn't use Qt/gtk2 for "image manipulation" if you actually mean "image processing".    There are several open source image processing libraries, take a look at the ImageMagick API interface, linked [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php), which has bindings for *many* images.  There's also the [gd image library](http://www.boutell.com/gd/) available for programmatic image generation, and it has bindings in many languages.

Comment: I need to do some screen scraping and wanted the fastest library for doing it.